# GetType Reflection Is Null @ qualified name

Tags: c#, reflection, asp.net-core

I have a AuthenticationWorker class that inherits from Worker. Should also mention this is on .netcore

I am trying to load a XML and define what kind of authentication and such and dynamically build the AuthenticationWorker based on parameters in the XML.

But I keep getting a null @ get type.

[image]

[image]

Also tired

```
Type.GetType("AuthenticationWorker");
```

UPDATE as requested
[image]

UPDATED AGAIN with length

[image]

Comment: Do you have a reference to the POSI_Master-API assembly on the project that processes the XML? Can you check the qualified name of the type with `typeof(AuthenticationWorker).AssemblyQualifiedName`?

Comment: @thepirat000 same project. Added another image.

Comment: And if you pass the string obtained to `Type.GetType(tmp)` do you get the type correctly?

Comment: Well it is a null

Comment: There could be hidden/unprintable characters in the xml document. Can you tell me what `workerName.Length` returns? Or alternatively type in `workerName = "Authentication"` and see if it starts working -- do NOT copy and paste from the document, re-type it in yourself from keyboard, otherwise you will just copy the hidden characters again.

Comment: @Quantic Updated with image again

Comment: Well that wasn't it because the length seems right at 14, though you could have unprintable characters in the other strings. But looking again I think you simply need to continue adding the rest of the string: `"... Worker, POSI_Master-API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"` (verify this yourself, don't just copy mine which I just freehanded and may be incorrect).